# How to access particular matrix element for all blocks in entire image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a 512x512 image , which i made 4x4 block for entire image, then i want access the (3rd row , 3rd element) of the all indivial 4x4 matrices and add it to the index values, which i obtained. Please help me on below code.

```
  [row col] = size(a);
    m = zeros(row,col);
    count = [(row-4)*(col-4)]/4;
    outMat = zeros(4,4,count);
    l = 0;
    for i=2:4:row-4
        for j=2:4:col-4
            l = l + 1;
            outMat(:,:,l) = double(a(i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2));% for each matrix i have to find(3rd row,3rd element of each matrix.
        end;
    end;
```

Adding the (3rd row,3rd element):

```
  m(i,j) = sum(sum(a .* w));  %index value of each 4x4 matrix % w = 4x4 matrix.
       LUT = m(i,j)+ outMat(3,3);%(3rd row,3rd element each matrix should be added to all m(i,j) values. In which i fail to add all(3rd row,3rd element) of all 4x4 matrices.
```

Comment: what is `c` and `d`?

Comment: i corrected . its row & col.

Comment: What are your "index values"?  I can't tell what they are from your post. Is this a single value? A matrix? This post is missing some information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to reword your question so that it's easier to understand, as well as allowing it to be easy for me to write an answer.

From your comments in Kostya's post, you have two images `img1` and `img2` where they are decomposed into 4 x 4 blocks.  `outMat` would be a 3D matrix where each slice contains a 4 x 4 block extracted from `img1`.  From this, you have a matrix `m` that stores a weighted sum of 4 x 4 blocks stored `outMat`.

Next, you'll have another matrix, let's call this `outMat2`, which also is a 3D matrix where each slice is a 4 x 4 block extracted from `img2`.   From this 3D matrix, you wish to extract the third row and third column of each block, add this to the corresponding position of `m` and store the output into a variable called `LUT`.

All you have to do is extract a single vector that slices through all of the slices located at the third row and third column.  You would then have to reshape this into a matrix that is the same size as `m` then add this on top of `m` and store it into a variable called `LUT`.  Bear in mind that if we reshape this into a matrix, the reshaping will be done in **column major** format, and so you would stack the values by columns.  Because your blocks were created **row-wise**, what we need to do reshape this matrix so that it has `size(m,2)` rows and `size(m,1)` columns then transpose it.

Therefore:

```
vec = outMat2(3,3,:);
vec = vec(:); %// Make sure it's a 1D vector
m2 = reshape(vec, size(m,2), size(m,1)).';
LUT = m + m2;
```

`LUT` will contain a 2D matrix where each element contains the weighted sum of the 4 x 4 blocks from `img1` with the corresponding third row, third column of each block in `img2`.

---

Next time, please update your question so that you have all of the information.  We shouldn't have to dig through your comments to figure out what you want.

Comment: m2 = reshape(vec, size(m,2), size(m,1)).';
??? Error using ==> reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.  I got the error msg, can u tell pls why im getting this error

Comment: @STripathy Make sure your `for` loop constraints **do not change** for `m` and for the second image.  It's not working because `m` is not the same size as I expected it to be from the second for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do just

```
LUT = sum( sum( a(3:4:row,3:4,col) * w(3,3) ) );
```

Comment: Maybe i miss something, but I think my code does this.  Your outMat(3,3) is a (3,3) element of pointwise product of a and w. You can switch order of perations: first, select (3,3) element of every block of the image (i.e.  a(3:4:row,3:4,col) ), than multiply it by w(3,3) and sum

Comment: I tried like ,LUT = a(3:4:i,3:4:j)+ m(i,j); and Result: all the image pixel value as 255, where as i m trying to Add 3rd row ,3rd element of the each 4x4 matrix to corresponding idex values of all possible 4x4 blocks for entire image.

Comment: Hmm, I think your code is now doing something very different. Probably, just post a small example, 8x8 matrix a(8,8), and what you want to get in LUT.

Comment: say, i have 2 images(Img1,Img2).for both images i have to divide it  4x4 blocks., And then for Img1 i have to find the index value for each block (i.e with m(i,j) = sum(sum(Img1 .* 4x4matrix))).Then for Img2 again i ve to divide it into 4x4 blocks.Then i need to find the Img2(3rd row,3rd element) of all 4x4 blocks in Img2 , and the add it to the index values stored in m(i,j).(i.e LUT = m(i,j)+outMat(3,3)) .LUT must a Array, contain no. of Indexes in one row and in 2nd row the addition values.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. This wasn't clear in your original post. I'll write an answer soon.